# May I install Quickly also on Kubuntu?

Tags: application-development

I have installed Kubuntu. Now I would develop applications for Ubuntu with Quickly; have I to uninstall Kubuntu and Install Ubuntu or there's a way to mantain Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work fine. Kubuntu is Ubuntu still just the desktop is different.

I have never used it but a quick Google shows many people who are, you should easily find a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You may install quickly on kubuntu just as you would any other software package (`sudo apt-get install quickly`), you may be required to pull in a lot of gnome packages though, so it might take a while to install.